# Add Microsoft.Office.InterOp.Word using reference C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, ms-office

I'm trying to add the Microsoft Office InterOperability  reference to my header but I cannot find it.

I went here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kh3965hw.aspx

I installed the PIAs but I cannot find the reference still. There is a registry entry in the Add and Remove Programs but for some reason Visual Studio 2010 is not seeing it.

Edit: I have Visual C# 2010 Express

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio will install these Office PIA files as well to the following:

> When you install Visual Studio, the PIAs are automatically installed to a location in the file system, outside of the global assembly cache. When you create a new project, Visual Studio automatically adds references to these copies of the PIAs to your project. Visual Studio uses these copies of the PIAs, instead of the assemblies in the global assembly cache, to resolve type references when you develop and build your project.
>
> These copies of the PIAs help Visual Studio avoid several development issues that can occur when different versions of the PIAs are registered in the global assembly cache.
>
> Visual Studio installs these copies of PIAs to the following locations on the development computer:
>
> - %ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Visual Studio Tools for Office\PIA\Office14
>
>   - (or %ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Visual Studio Tools for Office\PIA\Office14 on 64-bit operating systems)
> - %ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Visual Studio Tools for Office\PIA\Office15
>
>   - (or %ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Visual Studio Tools for Office\PIA\Office15 on 64-bit operating systems)

Did you include the Office files when installing Visual Studio?

If not, then run Visual Studio setup again and choose to Add Options and choose the Office PIA relevant pieces.

Comment: I have visual C# 2010 Express installed. Is it not possible to get this on Express? I just tried uninstalling Express and re-downloading. There was Add Options section of the install wizard or anything that sounds similar on the install web site.

Comment: When I installed Visual Studio 2010 Professional the problem was resolved. On installing VS2010 Prof it clearly shows that microsoft office word dlls are installed.